# Should @autoreleasepool function could be used manually for memory managment?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently building an app that pulls large JSON file via an API request.

During the download-decoding-storing the data I get memory warnings (over 500MB).I found a solution to avoid to overload the memory and keep it at most at 300MB by adding  `@autoreleasepool { }` function manually.

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSString * result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];//150
    decodeData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:result options:0];//100
}

@autoreleasepool {
    NSString * decodeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodeData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//100

    NSError * jsonError;
    NSData * objectData = [decodeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//100
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];//50
    if(!jsonError){
        [defults setObject:json forKey:@"data_object"];//50
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this for memory management?

Comment: Do not create object that goes to autorelease pool, even if  you are using ARC. Crete objects based on the “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” rule, this object will be released at the end of the scope by ARC. Unfortunately for JSONSerialization there is no equivalent, I guess @autorelease is the right solution even if is not very performant

Comment: According to previous comment you can add separate methods for each action. ARC will release unneeded objects itself at the end of each method.

Comment: thanks @Andrea but the memory is full before getting to the end of the scope. so i need the best solution for that...

Comment: @Andrea, I believe you are confused about how ARC works.  Objects that used to be autoreleased under the MMM rules still work that way.  There's an autorelease pool that wraps the main runloop, which is what most code relies on.  However, background threads have to create their own pool, which is most easily done by wrapping the main entry point in an  `@autorelease` block.  Any code which is creating autoreleased objects en mass (such as in a loop) should wrap the code locally to allow cleanup to happen sooner.

Comment: @Avi yes there is something that I've never understood, but it seems that objects in ARC that are created with the old memory rules are treated in a different way respect what usually creates an autoreleased object. I remember an article that was exposing the assembly generated code, showing that most of the times old autoreleased object in a loop are not released at the end of it, but later, while old MM (init etc) are released right after. I understand that something during the years has changed, but I still believe that for ARC objects create in one or another way are not treated as equal.

Answer (score 2):

Placing an `@autorelease` block around code that generates lots of throw-away (autoreleased) objects is not only valid, but recommended.  This obviously also applies to few, large objects :)

Code which is running on the main thread has an autorelease pool available, but it may not be enough.  The pool is drained at the bottom of the runloop, and if many autoreleased objects are created in a single runloop cycle, you may need a pool specifically to cleanup these objects to avoid running out of memory.  This happens often with loops, and it's recommended that loop bodies be `@autorelease` blocks in such situations.

In terms of your specific issue, 300MB for one JSON structure is pushing it.  If at all possible, you should try and break that up into smaller objects and parse them separately.

Comment: thanks, but since we are using ARC now ,isn't theres a way to release objects before the bottom of the runloop?

Comment: That's exactly what happens when you wrap your code in an `@autorelease` block.  The pool is drained at the end of the block.